# How to include a Wordpress header and footer on Gatsby static page?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, gatsby

I have a wordpress site, say www.example.com, but on one particular sub-directory I'm hosting a static gatsby page, so www.example.com/gatsby-page. I'm wondering how I can pull in the wordpress site's header and footer into the Gatsby page's index.html? Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Why not integrate `/gatsby-page` into Wordpress, instead of the other way around?

Comment: How exactly would one do that? (Sorry, I'm new to Wordpress!)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the following PHP code:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp/wp-load.php');
get_header();
include('yourpage.html');
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Note that you may have to change the directory for the require() section.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but do you mean I'm meant to include the above code in my Gatsby index.html? Or create a custom page template in my theme folder with the above code? I was a bit thrown off by 'include('yourpage.html');'

Comment: @chocobuckle You can do either. This code snippet is assuming you will load the final page as a .php file, but you can add this PHP code (without the include()) in your HTML if you just want to be able to load the page using .html. (You would paste your HTML after the first ?>)

Comment: Is the path for 'wp-load.php' relative to the Gatsby folder? So should it be...
```require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'../wp-load.php'); ```
I've tried it both ways to no avail.

Comment: @chocobuckle The path is relative to the root public directory. If your WordPress is installed to the root directory, it would just be `/wp-load.php`; if your WordPress is installed to a directory called, say, "wordpress", it would be `/wordpress/wp-load.php`.

Comment: Gatsby is built on React, which is a javascript frontend. It does not use PHP.